# FingerprintManagerCompat method had issues with Samsung devices

Tags: android, fingerprint

#### Problem

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=#####, uid=##### requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
    at android.hardware.fingerprint.IFingerprintService$Stub$Proxy.hasEnrolledFingerprints(IFingerprintService.java:503)
    at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints(FingerprintManager.java:768)
    at android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatApi23.hasEnrolledFingerprints(FingerprintManagerCompatApi23.java:39)
    at android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompat$Api23FingerprintManagerCompatImpl.hasEnrolledFingerprints(FingerprintManagerCompat.java:239)
    at android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompat.hasEnrolledFingerprints(FingerprintManagerCompat.java:66)
```

This issue has only occurred on some Samsung devices:

- Galaxy S6 Active (marinelteatt)
- Galaxy On5 (on5ltemtr)
- Galaxy J7(2016) (j7eltetmo)

*(data from crash reports)*

---

#### Current solution from research

After researching the issue, the only solution I've found is to add the following permission to the manifest:

```
<permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

This seems odd and I'm not sure if this is the best or proper solution.

---

#### Question

Why is this exception being thrown? Is the above solution correct?

I would really like more information on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue but unable to reproduce on my S6. Did you find a solution or some more information about this issue?

Comment: Samsung made some statements about it being a firmware issue and they should have a fix soon.  I just added a try/catch around the check to handle the bug and hopefully the users get the update soon. @jujujuijk

Comment: Ok thanks for the news @AnxGotta , hope we'll get this update soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a support thread with Samsung where it was mentioned that this was a Firmware issue with the devices.

**[LINK](https://seap.samsung.com/forum-topic/getting-javalangsecurityexception-permission-denial)**

I simply added a try/catch around the code to prevent the crashes.

This should be resolved in the Samsung Firmware update.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way to reproduce this issue. First you need to register a fingerprint on the device and set the lockscreen to `none`. Then I had to restart the device and open my app calling `hasEnrolledFingerprints()`.

As stated by @AnxGotta it seems to be caused by a Firmware issue. However I found a cleaner solution then adding a try catch. I just needed to call `isHardwareDetected()` before `hasEnrolledFingerprints()`.

Comment: But wont setting the lockscreen to none removes all the registered Fingerprints?